# Gstreamer UDPSink output issue

Tags: udp, gstreamer, gst-launch

I have the following command I am using but somehow its not letting me send it over network(local). if I view local it works but not when I try with IP-address.

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240 ! videobox left=-320 border-alpha=0 ! queue ! videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240 ! videobox left=1 ! queue ! send-config=true ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

this gives me error:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: link without source element
```

but without the udp it works fine.

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240 ! videobox left=-320 border-alpha=0 ! queue ! videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240 ! videobox left=1 ! queue ! mix.
```

my client side is this:

```
gst-launch udpsrc uri=udp://127.0.0.1:5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES, profile-level-id=(string)1, config=(string)000001b001000001b58913000001000000012000c48d88007d0a041e1463000001b24c61766335322e3132332e30, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)298758266, clock-base=(uint)3097828288, seqnum-base=(uint)63478" ! rtpmp4vdepay ! ffdec_mpeg4 ! autovideosink
```

what am I doing wrong? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is the reason you are not able to send:

"queue ! send-config=true ! udpsink" is the 'link without source element'

What is send-config=true? Isn't this a property for some element you didn't type there?

Comment: gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay send-config=true ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000  
i have this command which works for 1 camera, and i was trying to get 2 cameras to work.. so i extended the command to add 2nd camera.

Comment: This portion of the first command is wrong, it is missing the rtmp4vpay element after the queue: "queue ! send-config=true ! udpsink".

gst-launch finds a link without a source element as no element is specified there as it clearly states on the error.